# Azure SQL custom backup role

Tags: sql, azure, azure-sql-database, database-backups

We are currently running an Elastic Pool within azure to host all our databases.
We need to back up these to on-premise as well in case of an emergency, and for it we are trying to use sqlpackage.

Now initially i tried running it with a user which only has the db_backupoperator role, however view definition was also required. However i would not like to give the backup user complete db_securityadmin permissions.

So i've tried giving the backup user only VIEW DEFINITION access by using the following command

`GRANT VIEW DEFINITION ON SCHEMA::dbo TO [user]`

However i am still getting the error that i do not have View Definition permissions.

I've also tried adding a custom role, however that is not supported within AzureSQL

NOTE: Full rollout to grant access:

```
CREATE USER backupuser
FOR LOGIN backupuser
WITH DEFAULT_SCHEMA = dbo;

ALTER ROLE db_datareader ADD MEMBER backupuser;
ALTER ROLE db_datawriter ADD MEMBER backupuser;

GRANT VIEW DEFINITION ON SCHEMA::dbo TO backupuser
```

Comment: The syntax looks fine. It should work. Can you please share the error snip?

Comment: The error we are getting is: The reverse engineering operation cannot continue because you do not have View Definition permission on the 'DUMMY' database.